# PHP: Date diff without years

Tags: php, date, datediff

I'm building a function that shows a list of users that have their birthday within 31 days from the current day.

The birthdays are stored in the database as timestamp, containing day, month, year. If I want to calculate the difference between that date and todays date (using the Diff function of PHP), it always calculates the difference including years.

So for example:
date of birth: 10th of march 2000
current day: 25th of march 2016

Gives about 2.200 days as result, but I want to display 15.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why you don't use 'date' function?

Comment: how should I use that function to calculate the difference?

Answer (score 3):

you could just create a new Datetime variable, with the day and the month from the birthday and the current year as year. then check the difference.

Comment: What happens if it is 20th of december for example? It doesn't give back dates in januari I think? Because that's not in the same year?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly with SQL during SELECT:

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    DATEDIFF(
        CONCAT(
            YEAR(NOW()),
            DATE_FORMAT(t.birthday, '-%m-%d')
        ),
        NOW()
    ) AS dayDiff
FROM
    usersTable t
```

This will give you the difference in days between birthday and today, no matter birth year. If you want to filter them up to 31 days, you can add `HAVING`:

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    DATEDIFF(
        CONCAT(
            YEAR(NOW()),
            DATE_FORMAT(t.birthday, '-%m-%d')
        ),
        NOW()
    ) AS dayDiff
FROM
    usersTable t
HAVING 
    dayDiff BETWEEN 0 AND 31
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// set timezone
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
function timeAgo($time_ago){
$cur_time   = time();
$time_elapsed   = $cur_time - $time_ago;

echo "<br/>";
$seconds    = $time_elapsed ;
$minutes    = round($time_elapsed / 60 );
$hours      = round($time_elapsed / 3600 );
$days       = round($time_elapsed / 86400 );
$weeks      = round($time_elapsed / 604800);
$months     = round($time_elapsed / 2600640 );
$years      = round($time_elapsed / 31207680 );
if($seconds <= 60){
    echo "$seconds seconds ago";
}
else if($minutes <=60){
    if($minutes==1){
        echo "one minute ago";
    }
    else{
        echo "$minutes minutes ago";
    }
}
else if($hours <=24){
    if($hours==1){
        echo "an hour ago";
    }else{
        echo "$hours hours ago";
    }
}
else if($days <= 7){
    if($days==1){
        echo "yesterday";
    }else{
        echo "$days days ago";
    }
}
else if($weeks <= 4.3){
    if($weeks==1){
        echo "a week ago";
    }else{
        echo "$weeks weeks ago";
    }
}
else if($months <=12){
    if($months==1){
        echo "a month ago";
    }else{
        echo "$months months ago";
    }
}
else{
    if($years==1){
        echo "one year ago";
    }else{
        echo "$years years ago";
    }
}
}
?>
<?php
  $curenttime=date("2017-03-16 10:10:00");
  $time_ago =strtotime($curenttime);
  echo timeAgo($time_ago);
?>
```